# Inconsistent results from printf with long long int?

Tags: c++, c, printf

```
struct DummyStruct{
        unsigned long long std;
        int type;
};

DummyStruct d;
d.std = 100;
d.type = 10;

/// buggy printf, unsigned long long to int conversion is buggy.
printf("%d,%d\n",d.std, d.type);  // OUTPUT: 0,100 
printf("%d,%d\n", d.type, d.std); // OUTPUT: 10,100 
printf("%lld,%d\n",d.std, d.type); // OUTPUT: 100,10
```

Please tell me why unsigned  long long  to int conversion is not properly handled in printf. I am using glibc.

Is this bug in printf ?

**why printf does not do internal type conversion ?**

Comment: Thanks Mykola, Now I have corrected my mistake.

Comment: http://www.pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer/extracts/tips (is select broken?)

Comment: Most compilers will give a warning for the error you made - did you just ignore it? Or do you not have warnings turned on? They are there for a reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its your usage that is the problem.
Unless the types specified in the format string are exactly the same as the types in the parameters then things will not work correctly.

This is because the compiler pushes the parameters as-is onto the stack.
There is not type checking or conversion.

At run-time the code is pulling the values of the stack and advancing to the next object based on the value in the format string. If the format string is wrong then the amount advanced is incorrect and you will get funny results.

Answer (score 14):

The `%d` argument tells `printf` to *interpret* the corresponding argument as an `int`.  Try using `%llu` for `long long`.  And memorize this [reference card](http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/gcc/format_specs.html).

(So no, it's not a bug)

Comment: (It's a bug, but not with `printf` but rather above program :-))

Comment: @pixelbeat: I enjoy it every day.

Answer (score 5):

Rule one: The chances of you finding a bug in the library or the compiler are very, very slim. Always assume the compiler / library is right.

Parameters are passed to `printf()` through the mechanisms in `<stdarg.h>` (variable argument lists), which involves some magic on the stack.

Without going into too much detail, what `printf()` does is **assuming** that the next parameter it has to pull from the stack is of the type specified in your format string - in the case of `%d`, a *signed int*.

This works if the actual value you've put in there is *smaller or equal* in width to `int`, because internally any smaller value passed on the stack is extended to the width of `int` through a mechanism called "*integer promotion*".

This fails, however, if the type you have passed to `printf()` is *larger* than `int`: `printf()` is told (by your `%d`) to expect an `int`, and pulls the appropriate number of bytes (let's assume 4 bytes for a 32 bit `int`) from the stack.

In case of your `long long`, which we'll assume is 8 bytes for a 64 bit value, this results in `printf()` getting only *half* of your `long long`. The rest is still on the stack, and will give pretty strange results if you add another `%d` to your format string.

;-)

Answer (score 1):

With printf (which is  one of the very old functions from original C) the compiler does not cast the paramters after the format list to the desired type, i.e. you need to make sure yourself that the types in the parameter list match the one in the format.

With most other functions, the compiler squeezes the given parameter into the declared types, but printf, scanf and friends require *you* to tell the compiler exactly which types are following.

Comment: This is a direct result of the fact that `printf`, `scanf` and similar do not declare the types of those arguments - they can't, because that's the whole point of variable-argument-list functions.